# Laravel Excel exports date and time as custom

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

When using [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) 3.1 for exporting data it should format dates to dates and time to time. However both date and time are turned into `Custom`.

I have the following export:

```php
class Export implements FromView, WithEvents
{
    public static function afterSheet( AfterSheet $event ): void
    {
        $sheet = $event->getSheet();
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'H', NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2 );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'I', NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3 );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'J', NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3 );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'L', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'M', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'N', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'O', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'P', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'Q', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
    }
}
```

And the view:

```php
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $date->date )->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($publication->start_time)->format('G:i') }}</td>
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($publication->end_time)->format('G:i') }}</td>
```

Also tried with:

```php
class Export implements FromView, WithEvents
{
    public static function afterSheet( AfterSheet $event ): void
    {
        $sheet = $event->getSheet();
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'H', 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'I', 'h:mm' );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'J', 'h:mm' );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'L', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'M', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'N', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'O', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'P', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $sheet->formatColumn( 'Q', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
    }
}
```

Using the [`columnFormats`](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#formatting-columns) method doesn't seem to work as the data is gathered from a view instead of any data method in the class.

The formatting does work for `NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT` but the `NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2` and `NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3` will turn into `Custom` instead of `Date` and `Time`. So my question is how can I get an export with the `date` and `time` types set correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when using the below formats it will set the column to the right type.

| # | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NumberFormat | `FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH` | `FORMAT_DATE_TIME8` |